# How to enable oAuth2 resource server feature in spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I want to integrate oAuth2 resource server feature in my spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE application in order to protect api access with valid token issued by my authorization server keycloak.

Then to configure my application'security, i created a SecurityConfig class that extends org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
So when i override configure(HttpSecurity http) method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class, i want to use inside this method http.oauth2ResourceServer(), but this method oauth2ResourceServer() isn't available in this instance of httpSecurity.
So, please can you help to solve this issue ?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0.4 is almost 6 years old. It is out of maintance. You should update your application. If you still insists to use Spring Boot 2.0.5, then you could try `soring-security-oauth2`. However documentation is already removed.

Comment: Hi @dur, I upgraded spring security version of my app to enable this feature using the pom.xml file like this:  <properties><spring-security.version>5.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version></properties>